# Rails 4: Nesting resource, change URI but not controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to place my tasks into my dashboard/admin routes, for example rather than todos/, todos/new, etc. I would like dashboard/todos/, dashboard/todos/new etc. etc.

I have tried to do that here like so;

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :todos
end
```

Though this also changes the controller, which I don't want - I only want to nest the todos inside of the dashboard controller

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scope` or `path` as described in the [***Rails Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

```
scope '/dashboard' do
  resources :todos
end
```

***or***

```
resources :todos, path: '/dashboard/todos'
```

This will generate the routes with the path `/dashboard/todos` which maps to `todos_controller`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to route `/admin/todos` to `TodosController` you can use `scope`instead of `namespace`:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :todos
end
```

You could check the rails documentations about this point : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing